# Reject lines with time

Tags: c#, regex

I need a regex that could select from the following text:

```
  string test hello world!
    bitmap player player.png
terrain(test)
bg(sky)
label(asdasd,sd, sd,ad,adsad, ds){sdds}
00:30 test(asda,asdad,adsd)asdad{asd}
    02:30 test(asda,asdad,adsd)asdad
00:40 test(asda,asdad,adsd)asdad
```

returns the following groups:

```
{
"string test hello world!",
"bitmap player player.png",
"terrain(test)",
"bg(sky)",
"label(asdasd,sd, sd,ad,adsad, ds){sdds}"
}
```

i'd like to use `..:..` for avoiding the time.

thanks a lot.

i tried

```
(?<!\b..:..\s).*
```

but didnt work.

Comment: i would read the input line by line, and then you could discard the ones that match our criteria; namely `^\s*\d\d:\d\d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [this](http://regexr.com?2vfv3) (with multiline flag):

```
^(?!\s*[0-9]{2}\:[0-9]{2})\s*(?<captured>.+)$
```

Answer (score 1):

So .. You want any line not starting with a number? It's not very clear what your criteria are from your original question.

You could try:

```
^ *(?![0-9 ])(.+?) *$
```

Meaning, "start of line followed by spaces, followed by anthing that *isn't* a digit or a space, ended by spaces".

Comment: any line that does not start with ##:##(space)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I used additionally `RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace` that allows readable regexes and comments in regexes as well.

```
String s = @"string test hello world!
    bitmap player player.png
terrain(test)
bg(sky)
label(asdasd,sd, sd,ad,adsad, ds){sdds}
00:30 test(asda,asdad,adsd)asdad{asd}
    02:30 test(asda,asdad,adsd)asdad
00:40 test(asda,asdad,adsd)asdad";

MatchCollection result = Regex.Matches
    (s, @"^                  # Match the start of the row (because of the Multiline option)
          ?!\s*\d{2}:\d{2})  # Row should not start with \d{2}:\d{2}
          \s*(.*)            # Match the row
          $"                 // Till the end of the row (because of the Multiline option)
          ,RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);

foreach (Match item in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.Groups[1]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```